# A question about multivariable concave functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider a concave function $f: \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is it possible for it to be convex in a single argument when I fix the remaining $N-1$ variables or does concavity of $f$ in $N$ variables imply that it should be concave in each individual argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be concave in each individual argument.  (Concavity is a condition on how the function behaves on lines, so if it behaves a certain way along all lines, it will behave a certain way along a specific line.)

There is a chance it might be linear in an argument.  Then it would be both concave and convex at the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I thought as well, but I got confused by a false claim from a textbook: I knew that the solution to a certain minimization problem yielded a value function which is concave in a set of parameters and convex in another parameter. This theorem that I saw claimed that it was also concave jointly in everything but it turns out that it makes a mistake during the proof and the claim is false.